# programa que permita almacenar en una array bidimensional la hora de un gimnasio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

El problema es que tengo que hacer un código en el cual
tengo que crear dos array, una bidimensional con el horario y la otra unidimensional con los días de la semana. Aparte tengo que poner que el usuario introduzca hora, semana y la actividad ( ejemplo pilates ), y se debe comprobar que la hora y día son correctos y almacenar la actividad. Tengo la mayoría del código, pero no consigo hacer que guarde la actividad.

```
dies=["  ","dilluns","dimarts","dimecres","dijous","divendres"]
x=0
h=7

while x <=1:
    dia = int(input("Introduce dia 1-5: "))
    hora = int(input("Introduce hora: "))
    if hora < 8 or hora > 13:
        print("cerrado")
        hora = int(input("Introduce hora: "))
    actividad = (input("Introduce la actividad: "))
    salir = str(input("Quieres mas introducir mas datos?: ")).upper()
    if salir=='S':
        x=1
    else:
        x=2
    for i in range (len(dies)):
        print(dies[i],end=" ")
    print()
    for i in range (len(horario)):
        h=h+1
        print(h,*horario[i]
```

como resultado sale así: [image: resultado del codigo]

Comment: En python no existen los array, en su lugar están las listas, dejando eso de lado ¿se puede usar una estructurade datos diferente?

Comment: Imagino que si podria usar otra estructura por provar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas posibles de almacenar esa estructura. Puedes tener una "matriz" (que no existe en python pero implementaríamos como una "lista de listas"), o también diccionarios anidados.

### Con matriz

La solución con matriz tiene dos variantes. Podemos hacer que el primer índice de la matriz seleccione el día de la semana y el segundo índice de la matriz seleccione la hora dentro de ese día.

Ya que hay 5 días y 6 posibles horas, la matriz sería de 5x6, algo así:

```
horario = [
 ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
 ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
 ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
 ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
 ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
]
```

Como ves la matriz tiene 5 elementos (uno para cada día) y cada elemento es otra lista que tiene a su vez 6 elemento (uno para cada hora).

Si queremos por ejemplo acceder al miércoles, hora 9, habría que acceder a `horario[2][1]`, pues el miércoles es el de índice 2 (0=lunes, 1=martes, 2=miércoles), y el horario 9 tiene índice 1 (0=8, 1=9, 2=10, ...)

Este enfoque es engorroso porque necesitas convertir cada día de la semana a su correspondiente índice, aunque puedes ayudarte de la lista `dies` que contiene los nombres y usar por ejemplo `dies.index(nombre_dia)-1` para sacar qué índice sería. Análogamente necesitas convertir la hora a un índice, pero esto es más fácil ya que es simplemente `hora-8`.

Además tienes otro engorro a la hora de imprimir esa matriz, y es que está "girada" porque cada fila es un día en vez de una columna.

Otro enfoque basado en matriz es prácticamente el mismo al anterior, pero haciendo ahora que la matriz no esté girada. Es decir, el primer índice seleccionaría la hora, y el segundo índice el día de la semana. Esto hace más fácil imprimirla aunque es un poco más "antinatural", el elegir primero la hora y luego el día.

### Con diccionarios

Personalmente creo que este es el enfoque más apropiado, pues evita tener que andar haciendo "traducciones" de índices. El `horario` sería un diccionario cuyas claves serían los días de la semana, y los valores serían a su vez diccionarios (uno para cada día) cuyas claves serían las horas y los valores serían ya las actividades.

El diccionario (inicialmente sin actividades asignadas) podría ser así:

```
{'Jueves': {8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: ''},
 'Lunes': {8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: ''},
 'Martes': {8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: ''},
 'Miércoles': {8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: ''},
 'Viernes': {8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: ''}}
```

Un diccionario así puede generarse también con una línea de código, para no tener que escribirlo:

```py
horario = {dia: { hora: "" for hora in horas} for dia in dias }
```

Donde `horas` sería una lista con `[8,9,10,11,12,13]` y `dias` sería otra lista con los nombres de los días de la semana.

Una vez tenemos ese diccionario vacío, meter por ejemplo la actividad "Pilates" para el miércoles a las 9 sería tan simple como:

```
horario["Miércoles"][9] = "Pilates"
```

Ya solo te queda inventar la función que imprima esa estructura de datos como tabla. Si te atascas pregunta de nuevo.

**Nota**. Al igual que en el caso matriz cabe plantearse un diccionario "girado" en el que las claves principales sean las horas y las segundas sean el día, con lo que introducirías el dato así: `horario[9]["Miércoles"] = "Pilates"`